# Toogle slide on a tag and css proprety

Tags: jquery, css, slide

I'm trying to toggle box shadow property for a tag within `#bj-pagination`. I would like to achieve effect where box shadow slides from page 1 link to page 2 link when link for page 2 is clicked. Is this complicated?

```
<div id="bj-pagination">
<div class="pagination">
<span class="disabled"><span id="prev">PREV</span></span>
<span class="current">1</span>
<a href="pagination.php?page=2">2</a>
<a href="pagination.php?page=3">3</a>
<a href="pagination.php?page=4">4</a>
<a href="pagination.php?page=2"><span id="next">NEXT</span></a>
</div>
</div>
```

Here I am positioned on page 1. CSS for current page is...

```
#bj-pagination .current {
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #F6E128;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #F6E128;
    box-shadow: inset 0 -4px 0 #F6E128;
    background: #FFF;
    border:1px solid #E4E4E4;
    border-right:none;
}
```

I would like to when page 2 is clicked animate slide of boxshadow from page 1 link on to page 2 link

Comment: Please post relavant code

Comment: _Is this complicated?_ NO, but what you tried to achieve this?

Comment: I tried with animate css proprety, because I already have some divs for which I animate opacity, but this seems a bit to complicated since I just started with jq and js two weeks ago